# SQL SELECT Only Closest To 15-Minute Timestamp

Tags: sql, select, timestamp, subquery, case

I would like to do a SQL SELECT for the closest value to each 15-minute time value.  For example:

```
00:15,
00:30,
00:45,
01:00,
01:15 etc...
```

based on timestamps(time) that are not quite on the 00 second stamped using the following if have managed to round every value down to the closest 15 minutes but I only want the closest one e.g.

```
SELECT dateadd(minute, -1 * datediff(minute, 0, 
    cast(convert(varchar(20),[time],100) as smalldatetime)) % 15, 
    dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, [time]), 0)) as [TIMESTAMP],
    cast(convert(varchar(20),[time],100) as smalldatetime), [time], 
    tagname , value
FROM hdata
INNER JOIN rtdata
    ON hdata.tag_id = rtdata.id
WHERE tagname = 'M1_WH_004'
order by [TIMESTAMP] desc
```

(note: i need the inner join to pull the tagname as they are not in the hdata table)

produces:

[image: example data]

Therefore, for each 15 minutes, I only want the value closest to the 15-min boundary.  For the data above, it would be the 09:45:15.383 and 09:30:17.463 for the data for 09:45 and 09:30 respectively.

Do I need a subquery or case statement?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Further to this, a had a table that looked like the data in the solution (data for every 15 minutes) already and the subquery performed a calculation based on the last two values like so:

```
SELECT DD1.[TIME_STAMP] AS [TIME_STAMP], DD1.[kWh1] AS [kWh1], DD1.[kWh2] AS [kWh2], (DD1.[kWh1] + DD1.[kWh2]) AS [Total] FROM (SELECT a.ID
      ,a.TIME_STAMP
      ,(a.[1_M1_Wh] - (SELECT TOP 1 b.[1_M1_Wh] FROM TagCapture b WHERE b.TIME_STAMP = DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, a.TIME_STAMP))) * 0.04 AS kWh1
      ,(a.[1_M2_Wh] - (SELECT TOP 1 b.[1_M2_Wh] FROM TagCapture b WHERE b.TIME_STAMP = DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, a.TIME_STAMP))) * 0.04 AS kWh2
  FROM [TagCapture] a) DD1
```

How can I use the solution provided in this query?  I'm a little confused with all the subqueries.

i.e. so based on the data defined by the t subquery take the count value for one 15 minute subtract from previous and multiply to get required value where would I insert the t subquery in each FROM clause? I can't seem to get it to work. The above is just where the t query would define the two different tagnames for 'M1' and 'M2'.

Thanks again in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.  If so, then you can use `row_number()` to solve this.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by tagname, time15 order by time) as seqnum
      from (SELECT dateadd(minute, -1 * datediff(minute, 0, cast(convert(varchar(20),[time],100) as smalldatetime)) % 15, dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, [time]), 0)) as [TIMESTAMP], cast(convert(varchar(20),[time],100) as smalldatetime) as time15,
                   [time], tagname , value
            FROM hdata INNER JOIN rtdata
                 ON hdata.tag_id = rtdata.id
            WHERE tagname = 'M1_WH_004'
          ) t
    ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Ahh yes this worked just needed to change it to [TIMESTAMP] order by [time] as [TIMESTAMP] is the one getting rounded down to the 15min boundary the 'time15' should actually be 'timemin' just rounded to min : Select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by tagname, [TIMESTAMP] order by [time]) as seqnum
      from (SELECT dateadd(minute, -1 * datediff(minute, 0, cast(convert(varchar(20),[time],100) as smalldatetime)) % 15, dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, [time]), 0)) as [TIMESTAMP], cast(convert(varchar(20),[time],100) as smalldatetime) as timemin, [time], tagname , value...

Comment: Can you help with my extension to the question as above??

Comment: @user1801843 . . . You can edit my answer to reflect the changes you made.